# Loosing vertical scrollbar in netbeans nimbus LAF

Tags: netbeans-8, nimbus

I'm using Netbeans 8.0.2 and the Nimbus Look And Feel.
At a certain point, when the vertical scroll slider becomes small, it disappears.

Has anyone the same behavior or any fix for that problem?

EDIT:
This happens only in Nimbus and Dark Nimbus LAF

Comment: Meanwhile the bug is fixed

Answer (score 7):

There is a bug filed [here](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8134828). Assuming this is your problem, after setting your look and feel to Nimbus, try adding:

```
LookAndFeel lookAndFeel = UIManager.getLookAndFeel();
UIDefaults defaults = lookAndFeel.getDefaults();
defaults.put("ScrollBar.minimumThumbSize", new Dimension(30, 30));
```

Comment: HI
thanks for your hint. This is exactly the behavior.
Wait for fix from openJdk.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but add to where?